# Show an DisplayAlert at App.cs (Xamarin)

Tags: c#, xamarin

I am currently trying to constantly keep track whether the user is connected to internet or not.

I have the codes to check for connectivity and I want to be able to show a popup whenever the user is not connected to internet while using the app.

However, I can't put `DisplayAlert` at `App.cs` (Error: DisplayAlert does not exist in context).

May I know why is this so?

App.cs

```
public App()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var seconds = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
    Xamarin.Forms.Device.StartTimer(seconds,
        () =>
        {
            CheckConnection();
        });
}

private async void CheckConnection()
{
    if (!CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected)
        await DisplayAlert("No Internet Connection", "Please connect to Internet", "OK");
    else
        return;
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

DisplayAlert is a method of the page class.
However your app has a 'MainPage' property. So as long as the main page is set (should always be so after it's set during startup) you can use

```
Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert
```

or from within App.cs

```
MainPage.DisplayAlert
```

Comment: It worked, thanks! Anyway, if I may, do you know why does my `() =>` have error at the `App` method? It's saying not all code have return

Comment: glad it worked, please mark it as the answer. with regards to your lambda error, it's because it's expecting a bool response, so return true or false from within the lambda

Answer (score 4):

So you can do this, is working for me

`Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
{
     await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("No Internet Connection", "Please connect to Internet", "OK");
});`

Comment: Hello Dominik and welcome on SO! Please, could you make sure to explain more why the op code does not work and why would yours be a better option?

Also, where should this code go?

Comment: Hello @phaberest, I wrote that because if you want to use display alert in other class except mainPage.cs you would put Devce.BeginInvokeOnMainThread to saw the popup message, otherwise if you use class of "mainPage" only write Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("","","");